# Apache Logging one result in wrong access.log file

Tags: apache, logging, vhosts

I've created multiple CustomLog files(created logs for the different websites), via vhost.conf  so they aren't all being logged in the access.log

From there I've taken it one step further to isolate a folder, on that website, and log that information separately so the usage can be tracked.

The Code; with a few SetEnvIf Request_URI's removed (like the one for css and js) for easier reading.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin support@domain.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/domain.com"
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com
  ErrorLog "/var/www/domain_apache_error.log"

## flag image requests
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "(\.gif|\.png|\.jpg)$" image-request=nolog
## flag folder calls
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/folder/" folder-request=nolog

## set do_not_log if any of the above flags are set
  SetEnvIf image-request nolog do_not_log
  SetEnvIf folder-request nolog do_not_log

## only log if do_not_log is not set
  CustomLog "/var/www/domain_folder_access.log" common env=folder-request
  CustomLog "/var/www/domain_access.log" common env=!do_not_log
</VirtualHost>
```

All works great, with one exception. It would appear as though one particular result is cached and still being logged in the access.log file.

Example:

```
/folder/12/file-name.php
/folder/13/file-name.php
/folder/14/file-name.php
/folder/15/file-name.php
/folder/17/file-name.php
```

are all being logged, like they should, in domain_folder_access.log

```
/folder/16/file-name.php
```

is still appearing in the access.log

---

So,.. I'm using apache, with Windows/Wamp. And it would appear as though /folder/16/file-name.php is somehow 'cached' and it is being logged in the wrong file. What is the process to clear the information so that the file gets logged properly. (I've tried restarting) And again everything else is working as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After watching the access.log, and seeing a 'few' other files being logged in the access.log file, I came to the realization that those files that were being logged were coming from the secure version of the Site. i.e. https vs http

Updating the  in the config/extra/httpd-ssl.conf file to use the same SetEnvIf structure corrected the issue.

..a FYI to anyone else who might  Experience the same issue.